# Drupal multi-site, virtual hosts and CloudFlare

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, drupal, cloudflare

I'm hoping that someone with some experience with CloudFlare can lend me some guidance.

### Background

- Drupal **multi-site** hosting 200+ sites, launching new sites on a regular basis.
- **Single IP** for all sites, using Apache **virtual hosts** on Ubuntu VPS.
- Sites managed through Aegir.
- Each site owned by a member organization of our association.
- Our primary domain is `www.association.com`. Members of our organization receive a sub-domain for development purposes (see next bullet).
- Members initially access site at `member_name.association.com`. When their site is ready to launch, they point their domain(s) to our IP. Apache virtual hosting takes care of name resolution.

### Example Scenario

Let's say a member called ABC Corp, who belongs to our association, opens up a new site with us. They would initially access their site at `ABC_corp.association.com`. Once their site is ready to launch, they update their DNS records with their registrar to point their domain `www.abc_corp.com` to our IP.

### The Question

We're interested in using CloudFlare to improve the performance, security and up-time of our sites. CloudFlare's documentation indicates that:

> "[upon signing up] ...we have you designate two CloudFlare nameservers as the
>   authoritative nameservers for your domain (e.g., bob.ns.cloudflare.com
>   and sara.ns.cloudflare.com). You make this change with the registrar
>   from which you bought your domain (e.g., GoDaddy, Network Solutions,
>   Register.com, etc.)."

So, the parts of my question are:

- Will CloudFlare work with this configuration?
- Would each member of our association have to make the DNS update with their domain registrar for their site, or could we make the update once through our domain registrar (for `www.association.com`)?
- From your experience, is there anything more I should know about using CloudFlare with this configuration?

Your time and expertise are appreciated.

Thanks!